# Try Catch Finally - dispose of a reader

Tags: c#

In C#, I am using a `TRY..CATCH..FINALLY` block in my code surrounding the executing of a stored procedure.

If there is an exception, then in my `FINALLY` I want to close the reader - `PolicyResult` as well as the connections.

However, I get an error

> *The name PolicyResult does not exist in the current context*

`PolicyResult` is the DataReader defined in the `TRY` but it seems to not be recognized in the `FINALLY` section.

Why?

```
        public static IEnumerable GetPolicies(int? MasterPkgID)
        {
            // Create a list of policies belonging to the master package.
            List<AdditionalInterestPolicyData> additionalInterestPolicyData = new List<AdditionalInterestPolicyData>();

            // Set the SQL connection to the database.
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QUESTIONNAIRE2"].ConnectionString);

            try
            {
               // Open the connection.
               objConn.Open();

               // Get the list of policies by executing a stored procedure.
               SqlCommand PolicyCmd = new SqlCommand("p_expapp_get_policy_detail_by_master_pkg", objConn);
               PolicyCmd.Parameters.Clear();
               PolicyCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               PolicyCmd.Parameters.Add("@a_master_package_iden_key", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MasterPkgID;

               SqlDataReader PolicyResult = PolicyCmd.ExecuteReader();

               // Loop thru the results returned.
               while (PolicyResult.Read())
               {
                  // Add to the list of policies - creates a new row for the collection.
                  additionalInterestPolicyData.Add(new AdditionalInterestPolicyData(
                                                         Int32.Parse(PolicyResult["affiliate_id"].ToString()),
                                                         Int32.Parse(PolicyResult["master_package_iden_key"].ToString())
                                                                                   )
                                                  );
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                bError = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                PolicyResult.Close();
                objConn.Close();
            }

            return additionalInterestPolicyData;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the `using` keyword

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader r = PolicyCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    //DO STUFF
}
```

You can also define `using` scopes for the `SqlConnection` and the `SqlCommand` objects. After the scopes are closed, the objects will be disposed.

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection())
{
    ...
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
    {
        ...
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader())
        {
            //DO STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because everything you declare in try block is not visible in other blocks excluding nested and parent. Declare it outside.

```
 SqlDataReader PolicyResult=null;
 try
 {
   ...
   PolicyResult = PolicyCmd.ExecuteReader();
 }
```

Than check if it's not null

```
 finally
 {
   if(PolicyResult!=null) PolicyResult.Close();
   objConn.Close();
 }
```

Comment: I did but now get: Use of unassigned local variable.

Comment: Updated my answer: just assign it to `null` when declaring. And please read a book about c#, things you are trying to do are pretty complex, but it seems you lack of basics knowledge, no offense.

Comment: after declaring it, i now also initialized it to null. That message now is gone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PolicyResult is defined within the scope of the try block, and is therefore not available outside it (in the finally block, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Any defined *inside* the `try {...}` is visible only there - ***inside*** the `try { ... }`. If you want to access the `PolicyResult` in your `finally` block - you need to declare it *outside* the `try { ... }` block.

The preferred way of doing this would be to use a `using (....) { .... }` block, however, which automatically guarantees proper disposal and basically makes the `finally` block obsolete:

```
try
{
    // Open the connection.
    objConn.Open();

    // Get the list of policies by executing a stored procedure.
    using (SqlCommand PolicyCmd = new SqlCommand("p_expapp_get_policy_detail_by_master_pkg", objConn))
    {
           PolicyCmd.Parameters.Clear();
           PolicyCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           PolicyCmd.Parameters.Add("@a_master_package_iden_key", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MasterPkgID;

           using (SqlDataReader PolicyResult = PolicyCmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               // Loop thru the results returned.
               while (PolicyResult.Read())
               {
                  // do your stuff here....
               }
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this approach, where do I close the reader and connection?

Comment: @FirstLast: you can (and should) close it as soon as possible - but if you don't, then at the end of the `using (..) { ... }` block, the reader and/or command and/or connection will be automatically disposed (and therefore closed) for you

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, it really dosn't exist, since when you use try/catch you create a **scope**, any variables created in that scope will not be known outside the scope.

You can easily fix this by moving the decleration to *before* the try/catch block:

```
SqlDataReader PolicyResult;
// Other variable declerations

try
{
}
finally
{
  // PolicyResult was decleared OUTSIDE the try block so it is known here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `PolicyResult` before the `try` statement:

```
SqlDataReader PolicyResult = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare SqlDataReader PolicyResult before the try block if you wish to use it in catch and/or finally

Answer (score 0):

The PolicyResult object is declared within the scope of the **try** block therefore it does not exist or is not accessible from within the **finally** block.  Move the declaration outside of the try next to your declaration of the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

The try {} defines a scope separate to the finally {}

You must declare PolicyResult outside the try and finally, initialise it to null, and check if for nullness in finally before you close it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats becouse they are in different scopes.

Try to declare the variable before the try catch:

```
SqlDataReader PolicyResult;

try
{
    // assign PolicyResult
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    // use PolicyResult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least declare PolicyResult outside of the try block and I'd recommend instantiating it outside as well. Something like this should work:

```
public static IEnumerable GetPolicies(int? MasterPkgID)
{
    // Create a list of policies belonging to the master package.
    List<AdditionalInterestPolicyData> additionalInterestPolicyData = new List<AdditionalInterestPolicyData>();

    // Set the SQL connection to the database.
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QUESTIONNAIRE2"].ConnectionString);

    SqlDataReader PolicyResult = null;

    try
    {
        // Open the connection.
        objConn.Open();

        // Get the list of policies by executing a stored procedure.
        SqlCommand PolicyCmd = new SqlCommand("p_expapp_get_policy_detail_by_master_pkg", objConn);
        PolicyCmd.Parameters.Clear();
        PolicyCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        PolicyCmd.Parameters.Add("@a_master_package_iden_key", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MasterPkgID;

        PolicyResult = PolicyCmd.ExecuteReader();
        // Loop thru the results returned.
        while (PolicyResult.Read())
        {
            // Add to the list of policies - creates a new row for the collection.
            additionalInterestPolicyData.Add(new AdditionalInterestPolicyData(
                                                    Int32.Parse(PolicyResult["affiliate_id"].ToString()),
                                                    Int32.Parse(PolicyResult["master_package_iden_key"].ToString())
                                                                            )
                                            );
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bError = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(PolicyResult != null) PolicyResult.Close();
        objConn.Close();
    }

    return additionalInterestPolicyData;
}
```

It's worth noting however that this may not be the best approach. First of all you should probably already have your database connection open. Opening and closing your database connection for each transaction gets really messy really quick. You can easily forget to close the connection and if there's an error logging can be tricking depending on the context. If this is a web app it's best to initialize the connection through a session management system that will either open the connection as soon as the page loads or as soon as the first query is executed. This way your connection opening and closing logic is all in one place. Then it becomes safe to assume that the connection did actually connect in any subsequent code and you can handle any transaction specific errors with a bit more ease.